# Matplotlib imshow figure(2,2) image sizes proportional to axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to plot 4 matrices that can be assembled into one 2x2 matrix. For whatever reason, the last matrix D is too large. I would like its size to be proportional to its axes. I'm using Python 3.6.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 7))
axs[0, 0].set_title('A')
axs[0, 0].imshow(A, vmin=0, vmax=1)
axs[0, 1].set_title('B')
axs[0, 1].imshow(B, vmin=0, vmax=1)
axs[1, 0].set_title('C')
axs[1, 0].imshow(C, vmin=0, vmax=1)
axs[1, 1].set_title('D')
axs[1, 1].imshow(D, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You would want for matrix D to be the width of B and the height of C, is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code from the question, the subplot columns and rows are equal in width and height respectively. What you want is to make the first column and the first row 4 times larger than the second.

This can easily be accomplished using the gridspec's `height_ratios` and `width_ratios`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(500,500)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 7),
                        gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[4,1], width_ratios=[4,1]))
axs[0, 0].set_title('A')
axs[0, 0].imshow(A[:400,:400], vmin=0, vmax=1)
axs[0, 1].set_title('B')
axs[0, 1].imshow(A[:400,400:], vmin=0, vmax=1)
axs[1, 0].set_title('C')
axs[1, 0].imshow(A[400:,:400], vmin=0, vmax=1)
axs[1, 1].set_title('D')
axs[1, 1].imshow(A[400:,400:], vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I want :)